# Ball Trajectory in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have around 10 3D Coordinates and in UNITY 3d I want to create an ball path trajectory like the example below of Hawkeye. So far I created ten ball Game objects and they show up in the 10 coordinates I have (using very simple script to position these balls at each coordinate). How can I make it sort of "link up" the coords.

[image: Hawkeye example]

Comment: If it is a proper parabolic curve, then just apply a force and let gravity do the rest?  If you are confused about x-coords then since you have points it should be quite easy to reverse the values and get the angle and the force needed?  Else just lerp towards the points, if you want it so a path follows a ball then you can use particles that are solid.

Comment: Can you clarify your request a bit? Do you simply want to apply a motion to the ball and make it go through the waypoints or do you want to show an actual mesh representing the future path of the ball (like the picture)? In case you want to show the path graphically, do you only need it in the Editor, or in the game at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Short long history, you could use :

1) Vector3.Lerp >> so you can translate an object from one coordinate to another but it will look a litle bit sharpie because it will go from point A -> B in a rect line.

2) Use Splines >> this is the option One++ because it allows you to take more control in the curves and in the animation itself [here](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/curves-and-splines/) is an example.

3) If you are short in time you can try [this](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/84), is a plugin that maybe could help.